# atanf gives me wrong answers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, trigonometry

I was doing Exercise of Chapter 3 (Functions) from a Book Called C++ Modules for Gaming.
It is this one question I am not able to Do is to find atanf(4/2) of (2,4) which according to the book and my calculator should give back '63.42' degrees.

Instead it gives me 1.107 degrees.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void tani(float a,float b) //Finds the Tan inverse
{
    float res;
    res = atanf(b / a);
    cout << res << endl;

}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter The Points X and Y: " << endl;
    float x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;                       //Input
    tani(x,y);                           //calling Function

}
```

Comment: `stdafx.h` isn't used in this snippet. Might as well [edit] your question and remove it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`atanf`, and the other trigonometric functions in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) return results in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). 1.107 radians are 63.426428 degress, so your code is correct.

You can convert radians to degrees by multiplying by 180 and dividing by Pi (the `M_PI` constant provided by `<cmath>`):

```
cout << res * 180.0 / M_PI << endl;
```

Comment: Works But A tiny bit of Another problem. In Cosf() I cant get the right answer in Degrees by multiplying the Answer of Cos() Instead I need to convert the Input First then Apply Cosf() on it. Any Idea Why does it not work like Tanf()?

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you correct answer in radians.Simply Convert it to Degree!

```
void tani(float a, float b) //Finds the Tan inverse
{
    float res;
    res = atanf(b/ a);
    cout << res *(180 / 3.14) << endl;
}
```